# How to Add Mutually Data Collection

Tags: data-structures, c#-7.0, c#-8.0

For example, I will create a class called `Person` and the class will have a property called `relatives` that type of person. When we add relative to person it will also add the person to relatives of the relative. But problem is I don't know how to do that. If you would help me, I will be very appericiate!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your `Person` class could have a member variable which points to a common `HashSet<Person>` shared by all `Person` objects which are relatives.`Person` objects without relevative could reference an empty set.